# how to use sphinx in rails and exclude results based on a column value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sphinx

I have  a simple query to show users that are active, but somehow it is still showing inactive users. I am using sphinx. The query looks like:

```
User.search keywords,:conditions=>conditions, :match_mode=>:boolean, :order =>sort_order.to_s, :page => page,:per_page =>per_page
```

the conditions hash looks like this:

```
conditions = {:is_expired => false, :is_disabled => false,...}
```

the condiitions include: :is_expired => false, yet it fetches those users which have :is_expired = true.

What do i need to do to make it only fetch those records that are not expired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changed the type of the column from boolean to integer, and it started working!

Edit: actually it started working locally, and not on production. I finally looked at the output of executing the command 
    RAILS_ENV=production rake thinking_sphinx:index
and saw a line that read something like: 
    ERROR: index 'user_core': failed to create /path/to/application/production/user_core.spm:     Permission denied.

Then i saw that the file permission was of "root root" instead of the user who runs the index command. This was because once the deployer did a "sudo su -" etc to deploy, and the new files created were with root as creator etc. I had to delete the file and it started working correctly after running the index command. I am not sure whether now i can revert from integer column type to boolean though.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ThinkingSphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you index the is_expired and the is_disabled methods. Apologies if you have done so already.